# В чем разница между явным и неявным созданием экземпляров шаблона функции?

Tags: c++, функции, generics

Допустим есть шаблон функции:

```
template <class T>
void func(T x, T y);
```

При вызове в коде этой функции, например, с параметрами int, произойдет неявное создание экземпляра шаблона.

Но можно явно создать экземпляр:

```
template void func<float>(float x, float y);
```

В чем разница между явным и неявным созданием экземпляра шаблона функции? Для чего вообще было введено явное создание экземпляра шаблона функции?

Comment: для того, чтобы определить в специализации логику, отличную от той, что прописана в основном шаблоне. Например кода у вас есть функция `isEqual` которая сравнивает два значения оператором `==` и возварщает `bool` - такая функция не будет корректно работать с `float` (погрешность), так что можно написать специализацию для дробных чисел, которая будет апроксимировать их для сравнения

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Но я спрашиваю не про явную специализацию, а про явное и неявное создание экземпляра шаблона функции.

Comment: извиняюсь, неверно вас понял

Comment: Если вы предполагаете, что с разных единиц трансляции будет вызвана функция с данными типами аргументов. Чтобы каждый раз, в точке инстацирования не генерировать код функции, а делать это один раз.

Answer (score 3):

Это может быть нужно, когда шаблон определяется только для нескольких вариантов в определенной единице трансляции. Обычно так делают чтобы экспортировать эти варианты из dll

Comment: Честно говоря я ничего не понял. Я на данный момент даже не знаю как dll библиотеки создавать, и что такое единица трансляции я тоже не в курсе)  Может это используется как то еще? (не только для dll-библиотек) p.s. +1 всё равно поставил